# Heuristics to detect a scan/attack to our REST API

Tags: regex, rest, security, heuristics

I'm developing a REST API and I've programmed a controller that handles the "undhandled" routes (routes for "resources types" that don't exist).

I've created some code to detect in an heuristic way potential attack attempts and log them (to later make actions like blocking IPs, or feeding a machine learning system).

I'm only analizing the request's route (and not its body). The regexp I'm using is the following:

```
const SUSPICIOUS_PATH_COMPONENTS = '\.\.|sys|shadow|passwd';
const SUSPICIOUS_FILE_EXTENSIONS = '\.jsp|\.asp|\.php|\.pl';
const SUSPICIOUS_AUTH_ATTEMPT    = 'admin|root|auth|login|password';
const SUSPICIOUS_CONFIG_ATTEMPT  = 'config|setting';
const SUSPICIOUS_OF_INJECTION    = 'cgi|script|eval|execute|code|insert|update|delete|select|phpinfo';
const SUSPICIOUS_OTHER_KEYWORDS  = 'pass|install|super|secure|security|token';

// Heuristic regexp used to detect security threats
const SUSPICIOUS_PATH_REGEX  = '/'
    . self::SUSPICIOUS_PATH_COMPONENTS . '|'
    . self::SUSPICIOUS_FILE_EXTENSIONS . '|'
    . self::SUSPICIOUS_AUTH_ATTEMPT    . '|'
    . self::SUSPICIOUS_CONFIG_ATTEMPT  . '|'
    . self::SUSPICIOUS_OF_INJECTION    . '|'
    . self::SUSPICIOUS_OTHER_KEYWORDS
. '/i';
```

If the route matches the regexp, then I insert a line in the log:

```
$this->get('logger')->notice(
       'SECURITY: Potential malicious scan ('.$httpMethod.' request)',
        [
            'route' => $route,
            'client_ips' => $request->getClientIps(),
            'user_agent' => $request->headers->has('User-Agent') ? $request->headers->get('User-Agent') : '',
            'request_body' => preg_replace('/[^\x00-\x7F]+/', '', substr($request->getContent(), 0, 1024))
        ]
    );
```

My question is if someone have ideas about how to improve this heuristics, and how to improve the logging (do you think I should log something else/more?)

Thanks for your time and your advice.

Comment: What's the criteria? If I'm asking for new ideas should I send it to codereview? I posted the code to show what I already thought and implemented, to avoid receiving the same ideas I have.

Comment: @blueygh2 no. This question is specifically asking for an improvement of the heuristic approach. Asking for that is off-topic for codereview, since the recognition heuristics are considered a feature. Changing a feature is not what codereview is about. For more information, see ["A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users"](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/)

Comment: Have you ensured regular URLs can't contain those terms? e.g. disallow usernames, documents, etc from including "setting" in their names, or rewriting their URLs if they do? If not, you will likely face a huge amount of false positives and end up missing the real ones. You might want to use more specific REs on that basis.

Comment: regular urls are processed before this point, if the urls don't match with the regular urls then became handled by this controller.